# How to scroll in a tabelview when keyboards shows up?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, tableview

I have a `ScrollView` in which there are `TableViews`. I set when the keyboard appears, the content above the keyboard should move, so the keyboard won't obscure anything. How can I scroll what is above the keyboard, only when the keyboard is up?

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage the height of **UITableView** when the keyboard is up and down. Notification will help to manage state of wheather keyboard is up or not. According to state, we can udpate **UITableView's height**.

```
 -(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note{
    // get keyboard size and loctaion
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];
    NSNumber *duration = [note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSNumber *curve = [note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey];
    // Need to translate the bounds to account for rotation.
    keyboardBounds = [self.view convertRect:keyboardBounds toView:nil];
    // animations settings
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[duration doubleValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:[curve intValue]];
    // set views with new info
    _containerBottom.constant = keyboardBounds.size.height;
    CGRect rectTable = _tblMessages.frame;
    rectTable.size.height -= keyboardBounds.size.height;
    _tblMessages.frame = rectTable;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [self scrollToBottom];

    // commit animations
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note{

    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];
    keyboardBounds = [self.view convertRect:keyboardBounds toView:nil];

    NSNumber *duration = [note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSNumber *curve = [note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey];
    // animations settings
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[duration doubleValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:[curve intValue]];


    CGRect rectTable = _tblMessages.frame;
    rectTable.size.height += keyboardBounds.size.height;
    _tblMessages.frame = rectTable;
    // commit animations
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        // register for keyboard notifications
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];

    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
        // unregister for keyboard notifications while not visible.
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add add observer to check keyboard is showing or not.

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
    selector: #selector(viewController.keyboardWillShow(notification:)),
    name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
    selector: #selector(viewController.keyboardWillHide(notification:)),
    name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo? [UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
    print("Show") 
  }
}

 func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
    print("Hide")
  }
}
```

And then you need to do calculation for content to show when keyboard will appear and set content offset of scrollview.